# persist many to many relation in database symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

When persisting my entity from a form, I get the following error when flushing in database :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be an array, object given, called in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 519 and defined in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.php line 48
```

I think I am getting it in the object form but it must be in the array collection form
which I can not understand

any ideas????

Answer (score 0):

It may be both a wrong binding or an entity class misconfiguration. But without more code from you, we can't really guess what's going wrong :)